# Strange error at a ternary operator usage

Tags: c++

I have a following code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int i = 3;
    do {
        (i == 3) ? (std::cout << "Is 3.\n") : ++i;
        ++i;

    } while ( i < 4 );
    return 0;
}
```

And got a following error in response:

```
ternary.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
ternary.cc:5:43: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: The ternary operator requires both parts to be of the same type.

Comment: Don't write code like this.

Comment: @chris oh, thank you. that solves the problem. what should I do now with my question?

Comment: @ta.speot.is you mean that I shouldn't use ternary operator?

Comment: @chris put your comment as answer.. so that op can accept it

Comment: The ternary operator is not a replacement for if...else. It is an operator. Use if...else in your case

Comment: `(i == 3) ? (std::cout << "Is 3.\n", 0) : ++i;` works fine, although still, don't do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're abusing the ternary operator a bit, for any given `a ? b : c` I would expect the result to be stored *somewhere* and I wouldn't recommend `b` or `c` having side effects.

The root of your problem is that the ternary operator requires `b` and `c` to be the same/equivalent type. Andrew's explanation that they need to be able to "resolve to the same ... type" is probably more accurate.

For what it's worth, you can use a sleight-of-hand (or even more abuse, depending on your perspective) [to make the code work](http://ideone.com/UXg3CN):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int i = 3;
    do {
        (i == 3) ? (std::cout << "Is 3.\n", 0) : ++i;
        ++i;

    } while ( i < 4 );
    return 0;
}
```

Or, [more explicitly](http://ideone.com/rRDEST), make sure both are the same type:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int i = 3;
    do {
        (i == 3) ? (std::cout << "Is 3.\n") : (void*)++i;
        ++i;

    } while ( i < 4 );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The ternary operator requires that the two alternatives resolve to the same data type. You can't use it in the way you have.

The compiler is telling you the two types are different — it can't convert from `void*` (type of the first path) to `int` (type of the second path).

Comment: This always surprises people who have come to think of it as an alternate form of `if-else`.